# Grouping records - ROW NUMBER and PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table #Test (ID int identity not null, name varchar(100), primary key (id))
insert into #Test (name) values ('Ian')
insert into #Test (name) values ('Ian')
insert into #Test (name) values ('Ian')
insert into #Test (name) values ('Mark')
insert into #Test (name) values ('James')
insert into #Test (name) values ('James')
insert into #Test (name) values ('Henry')
```

I am looking for the output below:

```
Ian 1
Ian 1
Ian 1
Mark 2
James 3
James 3
Henry 4
```

All the Ians' have the same number.  All the James' have the same number.   I have been experimenting with ROW NUMBER and PARTITION BY but I have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a few ways, but `row_number()` per se is not one of them.

Here is a method:

```
select t.name, dense_rank() over (order by nameid)
from (select t.*, min(id) over (partition by name) as nameid
      from #test t
     ) t;
```

This calculates the min id for each name and then uses that for `dense_rank()`.

If you don't care about the particular ordering, you can use `dense_rank()` on the name:

```
select name, dense_rank() over (order by name)
from #test t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DENSE_RANK` instead.

```
Select  Name, DENSE_RANK() Over (Order By Name)
From    #Test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired output with:

```
with prep as
(
    select name
    , DENSE_RANK() over (order by c) [rank]
    from (
        select distinct name, min(id) c
        from #Test
        group by name
    ) a
)
select T.name
, prep.[rank]
from #Test T
inner join prep on prep.name = T.name
```

The first (sub)query selects the lowest possible ID per record, the DENSE_RANK then ensures the numbering is seqential, and the final query uses those prepped results against the original #Test table to duplicate the data per row.

You can find out more about the ranking functions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx